# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed

Tags: scala, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

Here i'm trying to add  time stamp to the data frame dynamically to this incoming data,

> {"action":"event","id":1173,"lat":0.0,"lon":0.0,"rollid":55,"event":"type","ccd":0,"fone":"ione","version":"10.1","item":"shack"}

to the above incoming data, im trying to append the timestamp with the below code

```
foreachRDD(rdd=>
         74 {
         75 val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
         76 import sqlContext.implicits._
         77 val dataframe =sqlContext.read.json(rdd.map(_._2)).toDF()
         78 import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
         79  val newDF=dataframe.withColumn("Timestamp_val",current_timestamp())
         80 newDF.show()
         81 newDF.printSchema()
```

which should yield me out put like below

[image]

**But this code is giving me an headache, sometimes it is printing the schema and sometimes it is throwing this exception at "*line number 79*"**

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed
>           at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:221)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnresolvedStar.expand(unresolved.scala:199)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$anonfun$apply$10$$anonfun$applyOrElse$14.apply(Analyzer.scala:354)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$anonfun$apply$10$$anonfun$applyOrElse$14.apply(Analyzer.scala:353)
>           at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
>           at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
>           at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>           at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
>           at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:251)
>           at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:105)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$anonfun$apply$10.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:353)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$anonfun$apply$10.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:347)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$resolveOperators$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:57)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$resolveOperators$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:57)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:69)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperators(LogicalPlan.scala:56)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$.apply(Analyzer.scala:347)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$.apply(Analyzer.scala:328)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:83)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:80)
>           at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:111)
>           at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:84)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:80)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:72)
>           at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:72)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:36)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:36)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:34)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.(DataFrame.scala:133)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$withPlan(DataFrame.scala:2126)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.select(DataFrame.scala:707)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.withColumn(DataFrame.scala:1188)
>           at HiveGenerator$$anonfun$main$1.apply(HiveGenerator.scala:79)
>           at HiveGenerator$$anonfun$main$1.apply(HiveGenerator.scala:73)

Where am i going wrong, please help.

Answer (score 3):

Came to know from the stackoverflow chat,

fixed it, like this.

```
df.withColumn("current_time",lit(CurrentDate))
```

As the second argument in the .withColumn() will expect a named column and

```
val newDF=dataframe.withColumn("Timestamp_val",current_timestamp())
```

will not generate a named column hence the exception.

Comment: haha I couldn't mention you in the answer. Thanks  @mtoto for solving my issue.